# Known incompatibilities between Java 1.4 to Java 5

Tags: java, backwards-compatibility, incompatibility

A list of potential compatibility problems is provided by Sun: [http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/compatibility.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20040207150306/http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/compatibility.html).

Have you encountered other problems when running/testing old-1.4-applications against Java 5 (e.g. A specific library no longer working ....)?

Comment: Do you have a specific library in mind?

Comment: Why would you move to 5.0 now? You do know it has completed its end of service life period?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may discover an alternative list of backward compatibility problems in all versions of JDK including 1.4 and 1.5 at the following web-sites:

- JDK-Results at [Japitools Home Page](http://sab39.netreach.com/Software/Japitools/JDK-Results/46/):

  > In an ideal world each JDK version would be perfectly backward compatible with the one before. As the following table shows, in reality this is not the case **...**
- Test results for JDK at [Java Upstream Tracker](http://upstream.rosalinux.ru/java/versions/jdk.html):

  > This service is aimed at monitoring and analyzing Java libraries development. It is looking for new releases of various libraries and checking them for backward binary and source compatibility **...**

These results were obtained by static analysis tools and can be used together with the official compatibility notes ([Incompatibilities in J2SE 5.0 since 1.4.2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-137462.html) from Sun/Oracle).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [Java 1.5.0 deprecated list](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/deprecated-list.html) may be of help.

Answer (score 0):

In general, code that runs under 1.4 should work under 1.5. I don't think any previously deprecated methods were even removed. However, bugs are fixed between releases and you might get some slightly different behavior if your application was written in such a way that depended on the bug (I have encountered this with a Swing application).